# How to interpret Givón's (1981) implicational scale for indefinite articles developed from numeral 'one'?

Tags: historical-linguistics, semantics, linguistic-typology, indefinite-article

I'm having trouble understanding the implicational scale for indefinite articles developed from numeral 'one' given by T Givón (1981: 50-52).

T. Givón in his paper "On the development of the numeral 'one' as an indefinite marker" (1981: 50-52) proposes an implicational scale for indefinite articles developed from 'one':

quantification > referentiality/denotation > genericity/connotation

He states that one can interpret this progression as an instance of semantic bleaching along a markedness/implicational space.

Regarding implication he says that (i) quantification implies existence/reference and (ii) existence/reference implies connotation/genericity.

Regarding semantic bleaching he says that the two transitions on the scale can be viewed as each removing one more marked semantic feature of 'one', first the quantification is bleached out and then the existence/reference is bleached out.

While I get the semantic bleaching part, I'm having trouble understanding the implication he is referring to. I was under the impression that the implicational scales in general are to be read right to left, i.e., the right most stage implying having the quality/functions of all the preceding stages to its left but not vice versa. Then in this scale how does quantification implies referentiality and referentiality implies genericity?

I would be really grateful if someone can help me understand this implicational scale. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the paper, but I think you're reading backwards. Quantification implies existince: if there is a definite number of things (at least, if that number is non-zero) then the thing exist. But the reverse is not true: there are things in existence that cannot meaningfully be quantified. Similarly, existence implies genericity, but the converse is not true.